# Use string indices with colon (lua programming)

Tags: string, lua, indices

I am learning the lua programming from a online book. 
It talks about string indices for an array

> If the indices are strings, you can create a single index
>   concatenating both indices with a character in between to separate
>   them. For instance, you can index a matrix m with string indices s and
>   t with the code m[s..':'..t], provided that both s and t do not
>   contain colons (otherwise, pairs like ("a:", "b") and ("a", ":b")
>   would collapse into a single index "a::b"). When in doubt, you can use
>   a control character like `\0´ to separate the indices.

https://www.lua.org/pil/11.2.html

I don't understand what is wrong with index "a::b".  What is the difference between "a:b" and "a::b". 
What's the trick behind it?

Comment: Both pairs `("a:", "b")` and `("a", ":b")` would result in the same index.  But you have only one storage for them: `m["a::b"]`.  That's a collision.

Comment: I think you are right. The Ambiguity issue is the key.

Answer (score 0):

What the documentation you linked is describing, is a way to represent a multidimensional matrix in a single dimensional table. After giving an example of how you can do this with number indices:

```
mt = {}          -- create the matrix
for i=1,N do
  for j=1,M do
    mt[i*M + j] = 0
  end
end
```

they describe a way to do the same thing with strings: "If the indices are strings, you can create a single index concatenating both indices with a character in between to separate them." A code snippet that would fit the description would look like:

```
str_idxs = {"foo", "bar", "baz"} -- table of the string indices
mt = {} -- matrix
for 1,N do
  for 1,M do
    mt[str_idxs[N] .. ":" .. str_idxs[M]] = 0
  end
end

print(mt["foo:bar"]) -- 0
print(mt["foo" .. ":" .. "bar"]) -- 0
print(mt["foo::bar"]) -- nil
```

As you can see in this example there is nothing special about the ":" character, you can choose any string to be a separator (including "::" if you really wanted). The reason why "foo::bar" is wrong in this case is because you never gave a value to "foo::bar."